# Posts likes works on Graph API Explorer but on the server returns empty array

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-php-sdk

I've been playing with Facebook Graph API a little bit and everything works just fine, I can get the feed of my page, the comments, but have a problem with likes.

It turns out that when I make an api call from Graph API Explorer like this:

```
me/posts?fields=likes.summary(true)
```

I get the correct response:

```
{
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 0,
      "can_like": true,
      "has_liked": false
    }
  },
  "id": "000000000_00000000"
},
```

ID is edited for this example. However when I make this call from server, I just get an empty array.

Does anybody know, what's the matter and how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that the method "toArray()" made the likes array empty. I'll find another way to convert the GraphEdge to Array.